# Dtpicker in VB6

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I am able to format my dtpicker using below code.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
 DTPicker1.Format = dtpCustom
 DTPicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
 DTPicker1.Value = Format(Date, "yyyy/MM/dd")
 End Sub
```

After get dtpicker value using below code

```
 Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Label34.Caption = DTPicker1.Value
    End Sub
```

But result is not formatted like as dtpicker displayed value.

```
Dtpicker value : 2015/05/26

Label34 Value  : 05/26/2015
```

How to rectify this issue ...?

Comment: dates do not have a format.  Formatting is just how it is displayed to humans.  The value remains the same (its a *date*).  Format it for the label to show it a certain way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use format function (same you did for DatePicker) when assigning value to your label :

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Label34.Caption = Format(DTPicker1.Value, "yyyy/MM/dd")
End Sub
```

Or even better, get format from DatePicker:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Label34.Caption = Format(DTPicker1.Value, DTPicker1.CustomFormat)
End Sub
```

I don't remember, but maybe DatePicker has a property giving you its value as text (having the correct format).